# How can i use Jquery in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I need to create a database for school. When I hover a object in my column 'Champion', I want to show the user a picture of the champion on the left side. I want to do this with Jquery. I have searched over the web, but i can't find the answer. here is my script:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stijl.css">
    </head>
    <body>    
        <?php       
            echo '<aside id="links"><p id="Aatrox"><img src="http://eindwerkstef.be/php/champions/Aatrox.jpg"/><p></aside>';
            echo '<form action="php54.php" method="post">'; 
            echo '<aside>';
            echo '<select name="sorteren"><option value="Champion">Champion</option><option value="Role">Role</option><option value="Lane">Lane</option><option value="Counter">Counter</option></select>';
            echo '<select name="sorteren2"><option value="Champion">Champion</option><option value="Role">Role</option><option value="Lane">Lane</option><option value="Counter">Counter</option></select>';
            echo '</br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sorteer!"/>';
            echo '</br><p>Wat wilt u Weergeven?</p>';
            echo '<select name="toonL"><option value="Top">Top</option><option value="Mid">Mid</option><option value="Jungle">Jungle</option><option value="Bottom">Bottom</option></select>';
            echo '<input type="submit" name="toon1" value="Toon"/>';
            echo '</aside>';

            mysql_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx');
            mysql_select_db('xxx');

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $query= "SELECT * FROM lolOverzicht ORDER BY {$_POST['sorteren']}, {$_POST['sorteren2']}";
                $res=mysql_query($query);
                echo "<table border='1' id='tbloverzicht'><tr><td><b>Champion</td><td><b>Role</td><td><b>Lane</td><td><b>Counter</td></tr>";

                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                    echo "<tr><td><p>".$row['Champion']."</p></td><td>".$row['Role']."</td><td>".$row['Lane']."</td><td>".$row['Counter']."</td><td><a href=\"lolwijzig.php?id={$row['Nummer']}\">Wijzig</a></td><td><a href=\"lolverwijder.php?id={$row['Nummer']}\">Verwijder</a></td></tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
            }

            if (isset($_POST['toon1'])){
                $query= "SELECT * FROM lolOverzicht WHERE Lane = '{$_POST['toonL']}' ORDER BY {$_POST['sorteren']}, {$_POST['sorteren2']}";
                $res=mysql_query($query);
                echo "<table border='1' id='tbloverzicht'><tr><td><b>Champion</td><td><b>Role</td><td><b>Lane</td><td><b>Counter</td></tr>";

                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                    echo "<tr><td>".$row['Champion']."</td><td>".$row['Role']."</td><td>".$row['Lane']."</td><td>".$row['Counter']."</td><td><a href=\"lolwijzig.php?id={$row['Champion']}\">Wijzig</a></td><td><a href=\"lolverwijder.php?id={$row['Champion']}\">Verwijder</a></td></tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
            }
            echo "</table>";        
            mysql_close();
        ?>

        <script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('img').on('mouseover', function(){
                    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
                });
                $('img').on('mouseout', function(){
                    $(this).fadeto('slow', 0.4);
                });
            });
        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use AJAX in that. To request data from database server.

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript and runs on the client. PHP is a server side language and only runs when the client (the browser) makes a request to the server. One of those requests is the initial page load, when you type the url and press enter. After that, you can perform AJAX requests from JavaScript/jQuery to the server to collect specific information. If you include AJAX in your searches, you should find plenty of results.

Comment: well you need ajax to request to database http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Another ready-to-get-sql-injection-query

Comment: BTW you have posted your database name, username and password. Please change your credentials  immediately!!!!

Comment: @bub he would have to delete the question entirely to be 100% safe, the details will always be present in the edit history

Comment: @andrew that's why he said change the credentials, not change the question

Comment: @cameronjonesweb exactly

Comment: @stef I edited your credentials. But you still have to change them.

Comment: Wuhu, database credentials, time to have fun!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see that you are a little bit confused.

**PHP** is a `server-side` programming language; this means that all the PHP code is rendered on the server before sending the page to the client (browser).

**JQuery** is a `JavaScript` class that aims to simplify `JavaScript` scripting/programming; `JavaScript`is a `client-side` scripting/programming language, this means that any `JavaScript/JQuery` code is executed on the client (by the browser we can say).

Alright, now about your question. If you want to show an image on mouseover event of a group of cells/column, you can do something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stijl.css">
</head>
<body>    
        <!-- the following code does not need PHP, so just leave it as HTML -->
        <aside id="links">
            <p id="Aatrox">
                <img src="http://eindwerkstef.be/php/champions/Aatrox.jpg"/>
            <p>
        </aside>
            <form action="php54.php" method="post">
                <aside>
                    <select name="sorteren">
                        <option value="Champion">Champion</option>
                        <option value="Role">Role</option>
                        <option value="Lane">Lane</option>
                        <option value="Counter">Counter</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="sorteren2">
                        <option value="Champion">Champion</option>
                        <option value="Role">Role</option>
                        <option value="Lane">Lane</option>
                        <option value="Counter">Counter</option>
                    </select>
                    </br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sorteer!"/>
                    </br>
                    <p>Wat wilt u Weergeven?</p>
                    <select name="toonL">
                        <option value="Top">Top</option>
                        <option value="Mid">Mid</option>
                        <option value="Jungle">Jungle</option>
                        <option value="Bottom">Bottom</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" name="toon1" value="Toon"/>
                </aside>
    <?php
        $address = "localhost"; // this is your database's address
        $username = "root"; // this is your mysql username
        $password = "1234"; // this is your mysql password
        $database = "example"; // this is your database
        $connection = mysqli_connect($address, $username, $password, $database);

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM lolOverzicht ORDER BY {$_POST['sorteren']}, {$_POST['sorteren2']}";
            $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            echo("<table border='1' id='tbloverzicht'><tr><td><b>Champion</td><td><b>Role</td><td><b>Lane</td><td><b>Counter</td></tr>");

            while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                echo("<tr>");
                echo("<td class='col-champion'>".$row['Champion']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['Role']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['Lane']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['Counter']."</td>
                      <td><a href=\"lolwijzig.php?id={$row['Nummer']}\">Wijzig</a></td>
                      <td><a href=\"lolverwijder.php?id={$row['Nummer']}\">Verwijder</a>
                      </td>");
                echo("</tr>");
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }

        if (isset($_POST['toon1'])){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM lolOverzicht WHERE Lane = '{$_POST['toonL']}' ORDER BY {$_POST['sorteren']}, {$_POST['sorteren2']}";
            $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            echo "<table border='1' id='tbloverzicht'><tr><td><b>Champion</td><td><b>Role</td><td><b>Lane</td><td><b>Counter</td></tr>";

            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                echo("<tr>");
                echo("<td class='col-champion'>".$row['Champion']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['Role']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['Lane']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['Counter']."</td>
                      <td><a href=\"lolwijzig.php?id={$row['Champion']}\">Wijzig</a></td>
                      <td><a href=\"lolverwijder.php?id={$row['Champion']}\">Verwijder</a></td>");
                echo("</tr>");
            }
            echo("</table>");
        }        
        mysqli_close($connection);
    ?>

    <img src"" id="img">

    <script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#img').hide();
        });

        $('.col-champion').mouseover( function(e){
            /* 
            Since I don't know where and how you decide which image to show, that's up to you 
            then to change img source just use:
            $("#img").attr("src","chosenimage.jpg");
            */
            $('#img').show();
            $("#img").offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY});
        });

        $('.col-champion').mouseout( function(e){
            $('#img').hide();
        });

    </script>    
</body>
```

**NOTE:** I changed from mysql to mysqli because mysql is deprecated now, I highly recommend you to use mysqli for your next projects.

**ADVICE:** For future questions I highly recommend you to explain every single detail of your problem, providing everything you think would make your question easier to understand.

Then if you need some fade effects you can give a look at JQuery's official documentation by clicking [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/)

I hope this helped you and good luck with your homework!.